# Energy conversion and momentum conservation law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Bullet ($m=0.02\ kg\ ;v_1=400 \ m/s$ ) hits pendulum ball ($M=3.98\ kg$) and system with stacket bullet and ball bends  to one side. Need to find max. delta height ($h$) (position change in vertical direction) the system reaches during maximum bending. No energy was emitted to heat.

Assume after hitting system starts moving with velocity $u$. According  to the momentum conservation law:

$mv_1=(m+M)u$  then

$u= mv_1/(m+M)$

So, $u$ is $2\ m/sec$

According energy conversation law:

bullet has energy $mv_1^{2}/2$ and all this energy was converted to $(m+M)gh$. So:

$mv_1^{2}/2=(m+M)gh$

If I do calculation, I get answer $h=40\ m$. And that is wrong.

If I look from another side:

$(m+M)u^{2}/2=(m+M)gh$

I will get $h=0.2m$ And this is correct answer.

According to my understanding both variants should return correct answer, because if no energy is lost after hitting whole bullet energy is emitted to system mullet+ball, so:

$(m+M)u^{2}/2=mv_1^{2}/2$

But why answers are different then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A perfectly inelastic collision (also known as a plastic collision) occurs when the maximum amount of kinetic energy of a system is lost. In a perfectly inelastic collision, i.e., a zero coefficient of restitution, the colliding particles stick together. In such a collision, kinetic energy is lost by bonding the two bodies together. This bonding energy usually results in a maximum kinetic energy loss of the system.

> In your case "*No energy was emitted to heat.*".

But Kinetic energy lost appears as the Potential energy of the reshaped system e.g consider two bodies are to collide as shown
 [image]
<sub>(source: [real-world-physics-problems.com](http://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/images/elastic_collision_3.png))</sub>
  but suppose there's a locking mechanism which locks these two bodies when the spring is compressed to a maximum value. This will be a completely inelastic collision and a part of Kinetic energy will used to compress the spring which remains compressed due to the locking mechanism. Hence energy is not dissipated as heat rather it is used to raise the potential energy of the system.

> Similarly K.E is not conserved in the situation you mentioned. So you have only the momentum conservation equation to solve the problem.

Comment: But in the contact moment system (bullet+ball) has no P.E.. and has K.E. that bullet brought. In the maximum bend moment whole kinetic energy was converted to P.E.. System starting point whole K.E. is taken from bullet. So, in starting point K.E.(bullet)=K.E.(bullet+ball at hit moment)

Comment: @user35359 Newton's third law! bullet will impart some force on the ball and similarly ball will impart equal and opposite force on bullet. Force acting on bullet will do negative work which will reduce bullet's kinetic energy(and reshapes the bullet hence increase P.E). The force imparted by the bullet on ball will increase the K.E of ball. Since collision is completely inelastic Force on bullet will act uptill both bullet and ball acquires same velocity. So starting point $K.E$(bullet)=$P.E$(system)+$K.E$(system). What would happen if ball was also moving towards bullet and after collision..

Comment: .. sestem(bullet+ball) stops. All the K.E will waste in increasing the P.E of reshaped system. Infact thats why you are getting different answers which ensures my point(example finished). P.E of system cannot exceed than maximum bent P.E corresponding to the bent bullet. The remaining kinetic energy of the bullet appears as K.E of system.